# what does -game and -rocket flag means in UnrealBuildTool and where can I find the help document?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, build, unreal-engine4

I am trying to use UnrealBuildTool.exe to build visual studio solution file, this code works but I cannot find any document talking about what does these flags mean and what's the other options.

And nothing happen for either "UnrealBuildTool.exe -help" or "UnrealBuildTool.exe -h"

code:

```
UnrealBuildTool.exe -projectfiles -project="C:/projectname/projectname.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK -rocket is a hangover from the beta days. -game builds a shippable version of your game. See this for more info:

https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?10948-What-is-quot-rocket-quot-mode

I found that by going to docs.unrealengine.com

Answer (score 0):

As for the second half of the question on finding the help documentation, there isn't any currently. You have to look at the source code according to the **UnrealBuildTool** section of [Unreal Build System](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealBuildSystem/index.html) from the official documentation.

You can grab/view the full source code on GitHub by following the instructions here:
https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github
(Wait a few seconds/minutes for the automated access invitation email after linking the GitHub account in your unrealengine profile.)

I find starting with **/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/System/UnrealBuildTool.cs** helpful on decoding the flags.